# Mapping keys on numerical keypad

Tags: vim

For years now I've been using laptops - without numerical keypads on their keyboards. Having recently acquired a dekstop keyboard ... just today I found out that Vim's mapping to numbers (1 ... 9, 0) don't work on their numerical keypad equivalents. What I mean?

```
nmap 1 Dj
```

doesn't work on the numerical keyboard 1?

Is there any solution to this problem *(not really a "problem", but annoying)*?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Windows: `nmap <C-k5> :tabnew<CR>`

The keypad identifiers are k1, k2, etc. Also kPlus and so on. As far as I can tell, the mappings fail when NumLock is off.

Comment: @ldigas Really? Works fine here. Vim 7.3 running on Windows 7 x64. But like I said, if NumLock is off then the mappings won't work.

Comment: @ldigas this comment might seem stupid, but your comment above is unclear: did you try `<c-k1>` or `<k1>`? First one requires `Ctrl` key to be pressed.

Comment: @kprobst - WinXP SP2 here running on a laptop with an external keyboard. Vim version 7.3. And I'm familiar with what the NumLock key does :)

Comment: @ldigas this one "<C-k1 or any other k>". I just thought you didn't try it without `Ctrl` key.

Comment: @ldigas the mapping works fine on this machine (WinXP SP3), and it should work as it is specified in `:h keycodes`. Possible it is related to be a external keyboard. There are some additional info in [vim-faq 20.4](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4) and [vim-faq 20.6](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.6).

Answer (score 1):

I have had some keyboards and terminals where I was unable to map via the `k*` identifiers. To map them in that situation, use <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> in order to input the correct escape code

So for example to map `1` on the keypad to perform `Dj`, enter:

```
:map
```

Then type <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, which will leave open an escape sequence with `^[`.  Then press <kbd>1</kbd> on the keypad.  The resultant code will look something like `^[Ow`.  Complete your mapping as normal:

```
:map ^[Ow Dj
```

Comment: :map, then Ctrl-v (which gives me just ^), and then pressing 1 gives me nothing.

Comment: @ldigas is your NumLock on or off?

Comment: On. When it is off, it gives the <end> (or <home>, or <up>, or <down> - depending on the key). Which is expected.

Comment: @ldigas Strange. I'm sorry, I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can map in vi (e.g. in `~/.vimrc`) the NUM keys in the following way:

```
inoremap <Esc>Oq 1
inoremap <Esc>Or 2
inoremap <Esc>Os 3
inoremap <Esc>Ot 4
inoremap <Esc>Ou 5
inoremap <Esc>Ov 6
inoremap <Esc>Ow 7
inoremap <Esc>Ox 8
inoremap <Esc>Oy 9
inoremap <Esc>Op 0
inoremap <Esc>On .
inoremap <Esc>OQ /
inoremap <Esc>OR *
inoremap <Esc>Ol +
inoremap <Esc>OS -
inoremap <Esc>OM <Enter>
```

This setting is an example for using the NUM key as they should be. Of course you can change the mappings.

Answer (score 0):

I also use keypad mappings a lot.  To help you get started with figuring out mappings, you can see what keys vim "knows about" and what there current mappings are with:

```
:h keycodes
```

Hopefully this will list you keypad keys as   etc etc.  If that is the case, then you can easily (don't have to worry about finding out and using their escape sequences) remap them using `map <k0> :wincmd w<CR>` for instance.

*For years I was using the Ctrl-v followed by a key to get the XXXX mappings previously until I found about the keycodes command, and the really helpful  definitions.*

Hope that might help!